# How do I get collaboration to work properly on a custom Cloud9 (SDK) install?

Tags: cloud9-ide

We have downloaded Cloud9 SDK (https://github.com/c9/core) on a server, installed it and launched it with collaboration enabled (--collab). This was surprisingly straight-forward and everything appears to work perfectly. At least when editing alone.

When multiple users connect to collaborate, everybody has the UserID -1. From the console:

```
CONNECTED UserID: -1 & ClientId: ...
```

In the Cloud9 chat, the only connected user is "You", and when editing a document we all have the same caret color.

---

How do we set up proper, separate users, preferably with full names and emails, and how to we connect to Cloud9 "as" those users?

Comment: That is not supported by the sdk, why do you want to use c9/core instead of ssh workspace on c9.io?

Comment: @auser Because connecting the browser to a server far away (Cloud9), which again is connected to another server far away (our server) introduces a lot of latency. So much latency, in fact, that the editor bugs out and erases text while I type.

Comment: @auser Also out of curiosity, if collab isn't supported on the SDK, why is it a launch option?

Comment: Collab is supported, but account management isn't. If you need to use cloud9 accounts with sdk I'd suggest you to contact to c9 support asking for that feature.